# python.exe was crashed when I run python **.py from windows cmd

Tags: python, crash, cmd

if I type python in win cmd, it's ok.But when I run python main.py from cmd it crashed.

The message is:

```
python.exe has stopped working.

  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4c73f7b6
  Fault Module Name:    python26.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.6.6150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4c73f79a
  Exception Code:   c0000090
  Exception Offset: 000c30a2
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2052
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Which Python are you using? CPython right, but what version?

If unsure try "python -V"

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? How about Python: is it 32 or 64? Are you running Python as an administrator or as a regular user?

Comment: I use 32-bit win7,and the Python also is 32-bit. regular user

Comment: So did I understand correctly: when you simply run "python", it works but with "python main.py" it crashes? If so I really really suggest you to check your harddrive for errors and/or to reinstall Python. After that, we could think if there is something else wrong.

Comment: When you run a helloworld.py with contents `print("hi")`, does the problem still occur?

Comment: Actually, when I type python in CMD, the interpreter works correctly and can print "hi" and do other things.But when I run python with a python file(such as hello.py),it immediately crashed.I think the interpreter couldn't receive the arguments.

Comment: I got this same issue when I had python3x something installed, do you have a second installation? and is your environmental path munged?

Comment: That's a windows server,I don't know if others change the installation of Python. I checked the path,it's OK

Comment: I reinstall the Python, now it's OK.Thank all you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-mortem: the problem was solved inside question comments (re-installing Python fixed the problem; I suspect the Python installation had somehow gotten corrupted).